# Advice on Recording a Conference

Tags: conference, microphone-positioning, microphone, microphone-technique

Hi all.

I've been asked by a friend for some advice on how to go about recording the audio for an event he's filming. I don't have much experience with events recording and am still a little green when it comes to suggestions for models of mic; I have some ideas on what to suggest but need some help filling in the details etc, please, and some feedback on my ideas!

The event is a publishing conference that runs over two days. The client wants both days to be filmed and edited down in to 5x 10min videos. It’s taking place in a church/town hall which generates a lot of reverb. There will be a number of people speaking throughout the day as well as questions from the audience. From what I've been told, is sounds like some of the speakers, when not being the main speaker, may be sat on-stage to one side and potentially interact with the the person currently leading the event.

I've been informed money is "no object really", but naturally it would be good to keep costs down. My friends has some of his own gear but will be renting anything else they need.

My thoughts were to, ideally, boom the audience (with Rode NTG2s, my friend has one of these already), maybe using multiple mics and operators if it's a large turnout; a short delay whilst an operator gets into position before someone asks a question shouldn't really be an issue, especially if it's all going to be edited down in the end.

A decent hyper-cardiod patterned mic should do for the main speaker, in a fixed location on the stage. I was thinking it would be a good idea to lapel-mic all the speakers, too, so that any interaction from those sitting to the side could be captured too.

**Can anyone suggest and (other) models of mic to use and any other advice on how this event should be captured?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Would you know if there's going to be a PA system in the venue for the event? If so, then getting a feed from it would save you from having to mic people.

And also, I don't think you'd want to have a boom flying around throughout the whole event.

Comment: Thanks fpr the advice! Yeah ok, maybe a boom isn't the best idea!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely find out if there is a PA system or perhaps an event company is providing the amplification and other services. If there is then, as soundspeed mentioned, just take a feed from the mixer.
I also agree that a boom is not a good idea for the audience, would be much better to have 1 or 2 radio handhelds that can be passed around, if you do this make sure to place some bright different coloured electrical tape on the mics so you know which one is being used. But if there is a PA then that operator will be taking care of that anyway.

Good luck.

Comment: Handhelds are a great suggestion, thank you! Yeah, a mixer feed sounds practical!

Answer (score 1):

if there's a lecturn, a simple gooseneck would capture your vocals

Answer (score 1):

If there is a PA use a line splitter to take a feed from every mic before it is sent to the desk.

http://www.canford.co.uk/Products/20-375_EMO-E375-LINE-SPLITTER-6-channel-3-way-3U-rackmount

Make sure that you warn the PA company, and that that you bring extra XLR cables.

Comment: Ah brilliant, using that'd simplify things, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do support the idea of taking a feed from the PA system, but -just guessing- there is always going to be some people that won't wait for the microphone to be on their hands to ask their own question, some may yell?  Maybe they ask an improvised but important question without the mic. I do encourage you to record from the PA, as well as recording the audience, but you will need several mics though. As mentioned above, a boom should not be your best choice, if someone is totally of axis you are pretty much screwed, compared to that of using maybe just a cardioid-condenser mic?